# List of wordpress Sites on Azure cloud

Tags: azure, azure-configuration

closingclosingclosingclosingclosingclosingclosingclosingclosingclosingclosingclosingclosingclosingclosingclosingclosingclosingclosingclosing

Comment: How many sites would you have to check? You will probably have to create a script/program using the management APIs to iterate the sites and e.g. FTP connect to all of them and check for wordpress files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Azure Resource Management APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn948464.aspx) to get a list of resources in a subscription or resource group.  Id recommend using tags to mark your website as Wordpress and then you can also use this API to query the resource tags.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. Just wanted to tell you I have hundreds of applications for in our azure and so many wordpress sites, till now no tags were created for any of those projects. If I add a new site from now I can add tags for this, but for all already existing projects which doesnt have any tags how to get those list. –  Wing Tin 9 hours ago

Answer (score 0):

Tag WordPress websites, as shown below:

1. Switch to new Azure portal https://portal.azure.com/
2. Navigate to your WordPress site (**Browse** > **Web Apps**)
3. In the website blade, click **All Settings** button
4. Select Tags at the bottom of the list.
5. Add a new tag WebsiteType/WordPress (key/value pair)
6. Repeat the above steps for all WordPress websites

Now whenever you would like to list WordPress sites

1. Navigate to Tags (**Browse** > **Tags**)
2. Search for WordPress, it will list all WordPress sites.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. Just wanted to tell you I have hundreds of applications for in our azure and so many wordpress sites, till now no tags were created for any of those projects. If I add a new site from now I can add tags for this, but for all already existing projects which doesnt have any tags how to get those list. –  Wing Tin 9 hours ago

Comment: I don't think there is a way to search for a website in Azure based on the template or framework that was used to create it and thus tagging for existing websites needs to be done manually.